# A serializable representation of a data type for client-server conformity checking

Tags: haskell

For a server-client application I need a way to automatically check the conformity of data structures used for communication. To achieve this I need to compare the serializable representations of those data structures. What I basically expect is something that would construct a type representation tree with primitive types as leafs.

E.g., the type `Artist` from the following data model:

```
data Artist = Artist Text Genre
data Genre = Jazz | Metal
```

would be represented as something like:

```
DataType 
  "Artist"
  [
    Constructor
      "Artist"
      [
        AbstractType "Data.Text.Text",
        DataType
          "Genre"
          [
            Constructor "Jazz" [],
            Constructor "Metal" []
          ]
      ]
  ]
```

Is there any library that implements such functionality and are there any better approaches to this problem? E.g., how do they approach this in Cloud Haskell?

Comment: Do you really need to check the conformity of the data structure on both sides?  If both sides are written in Haskell, then you're already guaranteed that it works and you just need a way to detect a failure of deserialization so that you know if data got corrupted.  Verifying that the data structure is well formed is what the type system is for, so why not just trust it to do its job?

Comment: @bheklilr It's simple. Versions mismatch. The server may be running a newer version of the app, which is protocol-incompatible, so instead of getting the protocol errors during the interaction I want the client to be rejected right away.

Comment: So why not just include a version in the document you send, check that first, then choose to accept or reject?

Comment: @bheklilr BTW, don't suggest version numbering, because it's error-prone due to human factor. I'm looking for an automated solution.

Comment: I see your point.  I seem to remember a library out there that was designed for this task, let me see if I can find it.

Comment: I think it was the [safecopy](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/safecopy-0.6.1/docs/Data-SafeCopy.html) library.  It doesn't seem to do quite all the magic you'd like, but you could probably build on top of it or modify it.  It looks to be a pretty small and well documented library, so you could leverage some of the ideas from it pretty easily I think.  Disclaimer: I have not used this library myself, so your mileage may vary.

Comment: I guess you can do it in Template Haskell...

Comment: @bheklilr Thanks, but it doesn't solve the problem. It requires the manual version specification.

Comment: If you just need to confirm the validity of the data, why not use a hashing library and a version-specific salt? Then just hash the data on the server side, and compare the hash on the client side once it's reconstructed?

Comment: @n.m. Sure. Probably with Generics and SYB too. And I'll probably resolve to it if there'll be no existing solution found.

Comment: @cdk That's on overkill, which would introduce overhead for data-hashing, while still requiring the bug-prone manual version control.

Comment: @NikitaVolkov: you might not actually need the version salt, since any change in the data structure (resulting from different versions) ensures that the hash will be entirely different. I don't think there would be significant overhead if you chose a fast non-crypto hash function. Are you sure any extra hashing overhead would be prohibitive?

Comment: @cdk Then all it will do is just produce an undehashable and hence an undeserializable value, which is not any different than with no checking at all, except with a redundant layer of hashing/dehashing.

Comment: In Cloud Haskell they use [`distributed-static`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/distributed-static-0.2.1.1/docs/Control-Distributed-Static.html) for this. In theory you could use it without incurring into extra Cloud Haskell dependencies, but to me it looks like trying to shoehorn dynamic typing in a language not meant for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have just released a [**type-structure**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/type-structure) library, which approaches exactly the issue declared in the subject. It constructs a data-representation of a type, while traversing all the types it refers to down to the primitives. Thus it transitively captures the changes to all types involved, which may even come from different libraries.

The produced graph has a `Hashable` instance, so it can be used to perform the matching aswell. E.g., one can produce a "version" hash with it.

Now, since the implementation uses typeclasses with CAF implementations, the construction of the representation data should be done in O(1). I have to mention though, that I haven't benchmarked it.

BTW, since types can be recursive, the library couldn't be implemented the way it was expected in the question, because it would construct an infinite tree otherwise. Instead the library represents the data structure as a graph. In fact, this graph is itself represented as a dictionary of edges, since there's no better way to represent an immutable graph.

### How to use

Here's a GHCi session, showing, how the library is supposed to be used:

```
λ>import TypeStructure
```

Construction of the type structure representation graph:

```
λ>graph (undefined :: Int)
(Type_Con ("GHC.Types","Int"),[(("GHC.Types","Int"),Declaration_ADT [] [("I#",[Type_Con ("GHC.Prim","Int#")])]),(("GHC.Prim","Int#"),Declaration_Primitive)])
```

Graphs of different types are guaranteed to be different:

```
λ>graph (undefined :: Int) /= graph (undefined :: Integer)
True
```

Graphs of values of the same type are guaranteed to be the same:

```
λ>graph True == graph False
True
```

Acquiring a hash of the typestructure:

```
λ>import Data.Hashable
λ>hash $ graph (undefined :: Int)
3224108341943761557
```

Hashes of different types should not be equal:

```
λ>(hash $ graph (undefined :: Int)) /= (hash $ graph (undefined :: Integer))
True
```

Comment: Cool. I took a swing at it using GHC.Generics, and couldn't recover enough information (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22733414/recover-type-definitions-using-ghc-generics), eventually arriving at the conclusion that it'd probably require template Haskell to accomplish what I set out to, or `Typeable` to accomplish a subset of it.

Answer (score 1):

Our generic serialization library [beamable](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/beamable) does this (otherwise it's a similar function to `cereal` or `binary`).  Look for the function `typeSign`.  The default `encode`/`decode` pair doesn't do type signing, but `encodeLive` will, or you can sign data types yourself.

Comment: Yes, it looks like a solution. Thank you. It's unfortunate however that it binds the user to a specific serialization library. I believe it deserves to be factored out into an independent library.

Comment: @NikitaVolkov it could be an independent library, but it certainly doesn't bind a user to using that serialization library.  You can simply use `typeSign` and serialize the resulting hash/data with any other library.

Answer (score 1):

As an SYB-based solution, there is a [**typehash**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/typehash) library, which generates hashes of a type structure using the `Data` instance.