# Recover type definitions using GHC.Generics

Tags: haskell, ghc-generics

Yesterday I took a swing at trying to answer [this question about a representation for a datatype.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22715572/a-serializable-representation-of-a-data-type-for-client-server-conformity-checki) using GHC.Generics. I could recover type definitions for the example problem given, for example, for:

```
data Artist = Artist Text Genre
data Genre = Jazz | Metal
```

with the derived `Generic` instances, default instances for `Modelable` (the class of things that can recover their type definitions), and a `Modelable` instance for `Text`

```
deriving instance Generic Artist
instance Modelable Artist

deriving instance Generic Genre 
instance Modelable Genre
```

we can determine that `undefined :: Artist` has the type of `Main.Artist` given the preceding type declarations:

```
data Main.Artist :: *
        Artist Data.Text.Text Main.Genre
data Main.Genre :: *
        Jazz
        Metal

Main.Artist
```

I represented the type with declarations so that we could also attack recursive data structures like

```
data ExampleTree = Branch Int ExampleTree ExampleTree | Leaf
```

Which we can determine is

```
data Main.ExampleTree :: *
        Branch GHC.Int.Int Main.ExampleTree Main.ExampleTree
        Leaf

Main.ExampleTree
```

The code I have so far covers all of these cases:

https://gist.github.com/Cedev/9857191

**Can we recover the types in a type application?**

Right now I have no way to tell the difference between a type applied to two different types, for example `[Track]` and `String ~ [Char]`. From the `Datatype` instance for `D` I can only recover the outside type, in this case `GHC.Types.[]`, I can't even distinguish the two types.

```
data Album = Album Artist [Track]
data Track = Track Int String
```

The following would be acceptable output for the type of an `Album`, but would be inefficient:

```
data GHC.Types.[] GHC.Char.Char :: *
        []
        : GHC.Char.Char GHC.Types.[]
data GHC.Types.[] Main.Track :: *
        []
        : Main.Track GHC.Types.[]
data Main.Album :: *
        Album Main.Artist (GHC.Types.[] Main.Track)
data Main.Artist :: *
        Artist Data.Text.Text Main.Genre
data Main.Genre :: *
        Jazz
        Metal
data Main.Track :: *
        Track GHC.Int.Int (GHC.Types.[] GHC.Char.Char)

Main.Album
```

Since I can't tell the difference between `[Track]` and `String`, the closest I can get is something like this, which presumes all `[]`s to contain `Track` since that's what was encountered first:

```
data GHC.Types.[] :: *
        []
        : Main.Track GHC.Types.[]
data Main.Album :: *
        Album Main.Artist GHC.Types.[]
data Main.Artist :: *
        Artist Data.Text.Text Main.Genre
data Main.Genre :: *
        Jazz
        Metal
data Main.Track :: *
        Track GHC.Int.Int GHC.Types.[]

Main.Album
```

**Can we recover the type variables in a declaration?**

An even better representation would share the definition of `[]`. This would require discovering that `[]` has kind `* -> *` and that the type of the first argument of its `:` constructor comes from the type argument to `[]`.

```
data GHC.Types.[] :: * -> *
        []
        : (Var 0) GHC.Types.[]
data Main.Album :: *
        Album Main.Artist (GHC.Types.[] Main.Track)
data Main.Artist :: *
        Artist Data.Text.Text Main.Genre
data Main.Genre :: *
        Jazz
        Metal
data Main.Track :: *
        Track GHC.Int.Int (GHC.Types.[] GHC.Char.Char)

Main.Album
```

**Can we recover type definitions for things of kinds other than `*` and `* -> *` ?**

Would it be possible to recover the definitions for things with more arguments?

```
data ThreeTuple a b c = ThreeTuple a b c
```

Which should be for example

```
data Module.ThreeTuple :: * -> * -> * -> *
        ThreeTuple (Var 0) (Var 1) (Var 2)
```

Would it be possible to recover the definitions for things with higher order kinds?

```
data Position f = {
    positionName :: f String
}

data Employee f = {
    employeeName :: f String,
    employeePosition :: f (Position f)
}
```

Which would be

```
data Module.Position :: (* -> *) -> *
    Position {
        positionName :: (Var 0) (GHC.Types.[] GHC.Char.Char)
    }

data Module.Employee :: (* -> *) -> *
    Employee {
        employeeName :: (Var 0) (GHC.Types.[] GHC.Char.Char),
        employeePosition :: (Var 0) (Module.Position (Var 0))
    }
```

Comment: The best place I know of to find examples of using GHC.Generics is the generic-deriving package (http://hackage.haskell.org/package/generic-deriving). The closest example is Generics.Deriving.TH, which seems to have gotten exactly as far as I did.